# How to check if a plc device is disconnected ,using OPCAutomation.dll

Tags: plc, opc

I'm using **OPCAutomation.dll** in **C#** to communicate with **PLC** device.

My question is:

- Can I check if the PLC device is disconnected?

Comment: What do you mean with: "plc device is disconnected"?

If it is turned off? or if it lost communication with the OPC Server?

Comment: Check what kind of public methods that DLL has. There is probably a method that tells/checks the connection status to the OPC server. I suppose you are having a OPC server at PLC? If not, then the OPC server that connects to the PLC should report the connection status somehow.

Comment: If you can't find the methods in the DLL, you can create a "life bit" and check the status from c#. You can also think to manage the exception generated when you try to exchange some data with the PLC but it is disconnected, so the connect method generate an exception.